# How to install network drivers for Void Linux on a x200 thinkpad?

Tags: wifi, void-linux

**Introduction**

I've installed void linux on an x200 thinkpad with a minimimal install using an ethernet cable as i couldn't connect using wifi.

**The problem**

> ip a

i have no ip address for my wifi device. I assume this is because i don't have the wifi driver installed:

> lspci
>
> 03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 5100 AGN
> [Shiloh] Network Connection

I've queried the void linux musl respository and couldn't find a package for 5100 AGN wifi driver. How do i install the driver to get my wifi card to work and thus connect to the internet?

Comment: It must be called iwlwifi in Debian according to my 1 minute Google search, it might be a clue, it might be wrong. Beware it might need firmware. I suspect you are better off with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the linux firmware packages:

```
# xbps-install -Suv linux-firmware linux-firmware-network
```

You will likely have to do this by chroot'ing into the root filesystem, since you do not have networking when booting into it.

Answer (score 0):

The Intel 5100AGN should use the iwlwifi driver so should be installed including the firmware with just the basic minimal void live USB dist at least with the glibc build. I am not sure about the musl. Everything worked for my basic install with glibc without using a network connection. Then I had to configure the wifi and could finally connect.

I think you might have a configuration problem. You can check the dmesg for any problems. You can try "iw phy0 info" and see what that says.

I always add a 70-persistent-net.rules to /etc/udev/rules.d/ so my wifi gets named wlan0 every time. That needs the MAC of the wireless adapter. Then I configure the wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf with wpa_passphrase. Then set up the /etc/sv/dhcpcd-wlan0 and start by linking in /var/service. This is all explained in the void wiki for networking.

If you are new to void then the desktop installations have the networking setup from the desktop with a graphical application and might be an easier way to begin than the basic minimal distribution.

EDIT: Maybe check the BIOS to see if the wireless card is enabled?